# MySQL - Index on VARCHAR Column with less cardinality

Tags: mysql

We have huge data in day wise partition with each partition carries some 20 Million rows and some 120 partitions.

Now, on table we have one `NAME - VARCHAR(100)` column and each partition contains some 70 distinct names.

So, does it makes much useful to put an index on `NAME` column as 70 distinct values with over 20 million rows in each `partition`.

Note: We are selecting partition wise (2 partitions).
      One more information: We are returning 10K rows to `GUI (via LIMIT 10000)`

Thanks.

Comment: Indexing without binding to application queries will never be wise - it's a subcase of premature optimization. (So you should look to queries which you're doing and their frequency, of course)

Comment: Are you doing "select * from..." or do you have some filtering conditions as well?

Comment: we are doing some 20 queries on that table in a day and most of those queries will be using NAME in where clause with some other columns too.

yes, we are doing SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME where partition_date between '01-12-2013' and '02-12-2013' and NAME='TEST1' order by time limit 10000;

Comment: Query:
SELECT * FROM table_name where partition_date between '01-12-2103' and '02-12-2013' and name = 'test1' order by partition_date desc limit 10000;

Now, as our table contains some 2.5 billion rows which sizes near about 450GB (including data and indexes).

inoodb_buffer_pool_size=8GB
Can't increase that too. So, no Q's of keeping all data in memory. IO disk operation will be there while fetching data.